# NiFi putFTP not efficient

Tags: ftp, apache-nifi

I have a nifi flow that sends more than 50 files per minute using the putFTP processor. The server has limited resources, but I need to send in a faster pace. I looked at the ftp server logs (not nifi), and my conclusion:

- A new ftp connection (session) is created for every file. Is there an option to configure many files on one session? (connect to port 21, authenticate once, and then send many files on different ports)
- When sending one file, many CWD (Change Working Directory) commands are sent. For example, sending file to /myfiles/test/dest/file.txt:

  > - CWD /
  > - CWD /myfiles
  > - CWD /
  > - CWD /myfiles/test
  > - CWD /
  > - CWD /myfiles/test/dest

This is not efficient. Is there any way to improve the putFTP? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

### First question: use run duration

> A new ftp connection (session) is created for every file. Is there an
>   option to configure many files on one session? (connect to port 21,
>   authenticate once, and then send many files on different ports)

First, (if it fits your use case) you can use the [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) processor to merge multiple (smaller) flow files into one (bigger) flow file and feed it to PutFTP.

Second, the [PutFTP](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/ea9b0db2f620526c8dd0db595cf8b44c3ef835be/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/PutFTP.java) processor has the **SupportsBatching** annotation:

> Marker annotation a Processor implementation can use to indicate that
>   users should be able to supply a Batch Duration for the Processor. If
>   a Processor uses this annotation, it is allowing the Framework to
>   batch ProcessSessions' commits, as well as allowing the Framework to
>   return the same ProcessSession multiple times...

Source: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/annotation/behavior/SupportsBatching.java

Increase the run duration of your PutFTP processor towards more throughput to use the same task for many flow files. You might want to adjust the `Maximum Batch Size` in the properties tab to accommodate to that change.

[image]

Read more about it here:

- [Dcoumentation: Run duration](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#run-duration)
- [Understanding NiFi processor's "Run Duration" functionality.](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/221807/understanding-nifi-processors-run-duration-functio.html)
- [What should be Ideal Run-duration and Run schedule configuration in nifi processors](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/222811/what-should-be-ideal-run-duration-and-run-schedule.html)

### Second question: inspect source code

> When sending one file, many CWD (Change Working Directory) commands
>   are sent. For example, sending file to /myfiles/test/dest/file.txt

By inspecting [FTPTransfer.java](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/75217b33d0fc43a64b1b80dd581561fda1ece904/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/util/FTPTransfer.java) you can see, that the put method does the following:

- put -> get client
- put -> get client -> resetWorkingDirectory -> changeWorkingDirectory(homeDirectory)
- put -> setAndGetWorkingDirectory

This might be the behavior you discovered.